# Label and Input text overlap each other when not in a bsModal

Tags: angular, angular-material, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using the asp.net boilerplate Angular framework and I'm trying to use the label/text fields that are in the user add popup, ie:

```
<div class="form-group form-float">
                    <div class="form-line">
                        <input id="editevent-name" class="form-control" type="text" name="Name" [(ngModel)]="event.name" required maxlength="64" minlength="1" class="validate form-control">
                        <label for="editevent-name" class="form-label">{{l("Name")}}</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

It seems when this is used in a bsModal it works well, but when used in a page the label does not move above the edit text see attached image. eg:

```
<div class="row clearfix" [@routerTransition]>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="card main-content">
            <div class="header">
                <h2>
                    {{event.name}} <span class="event-detail-header"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> </span>
                </h2>
                <ul class="header-dropdown m-r--5">
                    <li>
                        <!--<div class="btn-group" role="group">-->
                            <!--<button type="button" [routerLink]="['/app/events']" class="btn bg-black waves-effect waves-light"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i> {{l('BackToEvents')}}</button> -->
                            <button [disabled]="saving" type="button" class="btn btn-default waves-effect" (click)="backToPreviousPage()">
                                {{l("Cancel")}}
                            </button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                            <button [disabled]="saving" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect" (click)="save()">
                                {{l("Save")}}
                            </button>
                        <!--</div>-->
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="waves-effect" (click)="refresh();"><i class="material-icons">refresh</i> {{l('Refresh')}}</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <div class="form-group form-float">
                    <div class="form-line">
                        <input id="editevent-name" class="form-control" type="text" name="Name" [(ngModel)]="event.name" required maxlength="64" minlength="1" class="validate form-control">
                        <label for="editevent-name" class="form-label">{{l("Name")}}</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-float">
                    <div class="form-line">
                        <textarea id="editevent-description" name="Description" [(ngModel)]="event.description" class="validate form-control"></textarea>
                        <label for="editevent-description" class="form-label">{{l("Description")}}</label>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[example of overlap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooaMP.jpg)

Comment: I found the same and simply added a </br > to compensate in these situations.

Comment: Hi Guys, where are you adding the </br> ?

Comment: away from my pc so from memory it was just above '<div class="form-line">'.  i'm sure you can experiment :-)